# Boost::bind function getting Null values when a thread started with boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to start a thread in the following way

```
boost::thread new_thread(attrs,boost::bind(&foo, this, true, a, b));
```

true, a, b are some variables of the function foo.

attrs is basically some thread attributes.

```
boost::thread::attributes attrs;
attrs.set_stack_size(1024*4);
```

I get a segmentation fault in the process, doing a backtrace I find this:

```
0x00007ff4d7b02c74 in foo (this=0x0, boolval=false, a=0, b=0) at ..xyz.cc:1923
```

I am not sure as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more context please? Most likely the problem is the `this` value which according to your backtrace is null. You need to post more of the code that creates the `new_thread` object.

Comment: @Smeeheey the code works well without the attrs, i.e. boost::thread new_thread(boost::bind(&foo, this, true, a, b)); I was wondering if there is anything wrong in the syntax.

Comment: @Smeeheey that would imply that it's not GCC 6.1 ;) https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html